# Close cmd window after Git command in batch script

Tags: git, batch-file, windows-7

I wrote a short batch script (Windows 7) to bundle a Git repo and save a copy on a network drive:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /D E:/mypath/myrepo.git
start "Window title" "C:\pathto\Git\git-cmd.exe" git bundle create X:/outpath/name.bundle --branches --tags
```

This works as expected, however, I would like the window to close when complete. I tried `exit` but the window just returns to the directory specified by `cd`, and remains open.

How can I close the window? *(I've seen plenty of speculative answers in other posts, I'm asking how I can really/actually close the window in this case)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with :

```
start "Window title" "C:\pathto\Git\git-cmd.exe" git bundle create X:/outpath/name.bundle --branches --tags ^&exit
```

To exit the console of course you need `exit` command. To execute two commands on one line you ussally use [ampersand](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) . But in this case you want the exit as part of START command ,but not be executed after start so you [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) the `&` with caret.