# CMD window close after Batch file execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exit

This is my script which have autostart.

```
@echo off
call "C:\Program files\PrintFile\prfile32.lnk" /s:c:\PrintZebra\*.txt
```

Problem is that CMD black window on my Windows 10 is not closed after execution. I'm try make modification, but next script don't working correct.

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program files\PrintFile\prfile32.lnk" /s:c:\PrintZebra\*.txt
```

Some idea what I have test next?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637282/close-cmd-window-after-git-command-in-batch-script/41637342#41637342

Comment: Command EXIT dont work for me. My script run when windows autostart.

Comment: When you say _'after execution'_, you are sure that prfile32.lnk was executed? (is not running anymore)

Comment: If is execution correct I see like app prfile32.exe is opened. When changed CALL for START, app isn't open.

Comment: A very, very, very bad idea: If there is no other cmd-window open: `taskkill /f /im cmd.exe`. And no, one should not be doing that...

Comment: This don't working too. Black window is still open.

Comment: will `start "" cmd /c ""C:\Program files\PrintFile\prfile32.lnk"" /s:c:\PrintZebra\*.txt`  help? The extra `"` surrounding the path to the shortcut are important: `cmd` strips the first and the last `"` away so extra are needed

Comment: @MichalAB Why do you try to run/call/start the shortcut file `prfile32.lnk` instead of the application configured in the properties of the shortcut file? I have never seen before that somebody tries to run from within a batch file an application via a shortcut file.

Comment: Shortcut can be set to run minimized. Ideal would be if I can do minimize to tray. But I do not know yet.
Here is video what is doing: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5OmGqN_cPTjVEY4LWM4Ni1uLTA) 
App is started correctly, but black screen is there still.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `start /?`. As it can be read in output help there is the option `/min` to run the application with minimized window if the application does not ignore that request from Windows after start. Minimize to system tray is always a specific feature of the application extra coded in application as there is no general Windows support for this feature. It is also possible to specify the start in directory on using command `start` with `/D"Start in directory for application"` like in shortcut file.